# What is the meaning of "x places away from"?

Tags: meaning, word-meaning

I've seen a sentence **Ram sits three places away from Shyam** while solving a puzzle.

Does it mean *Ram sits fourth to shyam* or *Ram sits third to shyam*?

I understood it as *Ram sits fourth to Shyam* but I'm not sure of that.

I've found an explanation on this [website](http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/one-seat-away-from-me-next-to-me.2713939/).

But they didn't make it clear. I want to here explanations from you.

Is the meaning of *away* is *ambiguous*.

Can you please explain its meaning to me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Good question. I would expect "zero places away from" to mean "sitting on someone's lap", so "one place away from" would mean "next to", and "two places away from" would be the same as "next place but one". However, English is not always logical, and like you, I cannot find a usable reference.

Comment: A few websites say that it mean _three people sit in between them_ but a few say it otherwise. I'm confused.

Comment: If might be useful if you include those references in your question. It may save others some work.

Comment: I already mentioned one. I don't want to mention the rest since they are non standard and non reliable sources. But after seeing the explanation in the website which is linked to, I'm confused more.

Comment: Oh! well. We need an expert.

Comment: I agree with the usage of @Mick, but other speakers might calculate *# spaces away* (especially as compared to *sits nth from*) differently. There's no one right answer.

Comment: For instance, I agree with the guys on WordReference that *one house away from me* is ambiguous. Does it mean next door, or does it mean there's one house in between the two people? It's like *I'll see you next Monday*: this has different meanings and uses. Does it mean tomorrow, the 24th or the Monday after tomorrow? It's best to use more precise phrases: *his house is right next to mine*, *I'll meet you Monday the 31st.*

Comment: @AlanCarmack If an event is a week away, it means it will happen after a week. Similarly if a place is 30 miles from another place, it means that the distance between them is 30 miles. So, if A is 3 places away from B, doesn't it mean there are three places in between them? That's what I thought.

Comment: Perhaps so. But not everyone may agree with you. Again, if today is Saturday, then "logically" one can argue that *next Monday* is in two days; but not all native speakers will agree, and language does not always work by logic; many, maybe most native speakers will want clarification as to which Monday you mean, the one in two days or the one in nine days. It is the same with *# places away*. Stop analyzing this issue logically and just accept  what native speakers say, and note that not all will agree.

Comment: I expect *"zero places away"* to mean *"zero places in between"*, just as *"5 metres away"* means *"5 metres in between"*. So, *"one place away"* means there is one place in between. If there is no place between them, one could say they are *"right next to each other"*, *"they are adjacent to each other"* etc. to avoid ambiguity.

Answer (score 0):

As reference from the statement used in the question:
"**Ram sits three places away from Shyam**"

Which means that Ram is Three places away. For ease of understanding, 
Ram = 0
some person = 1
some person = 2
Shyam = 3

If you need more detail explanation [go here](http://www.hitbullseye.com/mba/reasoning/Circular-Seating-Arrangement.php)

Answer (score -1):

If a person is sitting x places right or left of somebody it means that there are x persons placed between the former and latter.